# Dynamic dropdown menu from database phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to show my website menu from database, but I cannot figure it out how to do the dropdown thing. If I leave it as it is, my header page will be full of pages from my database showing many times. Any ideas?

I changed the code so many times, don't know what to do anymore.

This is how my database for pages looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE `pagini` 
(
    `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `nume_meniu` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `pagina` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Meniu` int(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `pagini` (`Id`, `nume_meniu`, `pagina`, `Meniu`) 
VALUES (1, 'Dashboard', 'Admin.php', 1),
       (2, 'Adaugare Produse', 'Adauga_Produse.html', 1),
       (3, 'Stergere Produse', 'Sterge_Produse.html', 1),
       (4, 'Vizualizare produse', 'editare_chirurgie.php', 1),
       (5, 'Vizualizare produse', 'editare_aparatura.php', 0),
       (6, 'Vizualizare produse', 'editare_cardio.php', 0),
       (7, 'Vizualizare produse', 'editare_cons.php', 0),
       (12, 'Vizualizare mesaje', 'Viz_Contact.php', ),
       (13, 'Statistici', 'Statistici.html', 0),
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
require_once("connection.php");
$page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$IdUser = $_SESSION["user_id"];

$query = "SELECT pagini.Meniu, pagini.nume_meniu, pagini.pagina 
FROM pagini INNER JOIN drepturi ON drepturi.IdPage=pagini.Id 
WHERE drepturi.IdUser='$IdUser'";

$sql1 = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($sql1);
if ($rows > 0) {
  echo "<ul>";
  $sw = 0;

  while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($myrow["pagina"] == $page) {
      $sw = 1;
    }
    if ($myrow["Meniu"] == 1) {
      // echo "<li><a href='".$myrow["pagina"]."'>".$myrow["nume_meniu"]."</a></li>";
      echo "
  <div class=\"top-bar\" id=\"meniu-mare\">
      <div class=\"top-bar-left\">
          <ul class=\"dropdown menu\" data-dropdown-menu>
              <li class=\"menu-text\">
                  <img src=\"1.png\">
              </li>
              <li><a id=\"categorii\" href='" . $myrow["pagina"] . "'>" . $myrow["nume_meniu"] . "</a></li>";
    } else {

      echo "
              <li class=\"has-submenu\">
                  <a id=\"categorii\">
                      PRODUSE
                  </a>

                  <ul id=\"sub-categorii\" class=\"submenu menu vertical\" data-submenu>
                      <li><a id=\"categorii\" href='" . $myrow["pagina"] ."'>" . $myrow["nume_meniu"] . "</a></li>                    
                      <li><a id=\"categorii\" href='" . $myrow["pagina"] . "'>" . $myrow["nume_meniu"] . "</a></li>

                  </ul>
              </li>
```

Comment: `phpMyAdmin` is NOT a database, its a tool written in PHP

Comment: u need group by pagini.nume_meniu order by pagini.nume_meni asc in $query

Comment: You should query two times to make two or more dimension array and just print it out in HTML

Answer (score 0):

change your query to

```
 $query = "SELECT pagini.Meniu, pagini.nume_meniu, pagini.pagina 
      FROM pagini INNER JOIN drepturi ON drepturi.IdPage=pagini.Id 
      WHERE drepturi.IdUser='$IdUser' group by pagini.nume_meniu order by pagini.nume_meniu asc";
```